# How to add certain dp to fill_parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making an app that uses Android webview as the main component. There is a sign-in button on the bottom of the web page that I want to cut off. Is there a way to add a specified DP to "fill_parent" so the bottom of the webview goes out of the screen.

[What I want to cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7UyV.png)

Comment: Considering adding your current XML of your layout. Also, what you are trying to do especially with a webview will potentially work for one page and one device but it will be difficult to make it robust for several screen sizes and pages.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous Okay, but how do I add two values together, such as 20dp+fill_parent?

Comment: You simply can't do that.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous Okay, thanks for the help.